# Solr Tokenizer Injection

Tags: solr, tokenize

As an example I have a text field that might contain the following string:

"d7199^^==^^81^^==^^A sentence or two!!"

I want to tokenize this data but have each token contain the first part of the string.  So, I'd like the tokens to look like this for the example above:

"d7199^^==^^81^^==^^a"

"d7199^^==^^81^^==^^sentence"

"d7199^^==^^81^^==^^or"

"d7199^^==^^81^^==^^two"

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own custom [Tokenizer](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_0/api/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Tokenizer.html) and add it to the Solr classpath. Then use it in your Solr schema.xml and solrconfig.xml

Comment: After a bit of research this was my most logical conclusion as well.  If you can give me some good examples the bounty all be yers!

Comment: How do you know when the first part of the input reaches its end?

Comment: I could either define a different separator or we could just have it end at the last token ^^==^^.  Or something else if you have a better suggestion.  3 more days until the bounty expires :(

Comment: It seems obvious that one must subclass a Tokenizer but HOW?

Comment: start with extending http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-3_6_1/org/apache/solr/analysis/TokenizerFactory.html or http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-3_6_1/org/apache/solr/analysis/TokenFilterFactory.html

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters